# WIX UI Property Change Not Publishing

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have a edit control in WIXUI that's bound to a property

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_FILESHAREDIR">FILESHAREDIR</Property>
```

and the UI

```
    <Control Id="FileSharePathGroup" Type="GroupBox" Height="89" Width="352" X="8" Y="96" Text="File Share"/>
    <Control Id="FileSharePathLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="114" Width="69" Height="13" Text="File Share Path"/>
    <Control Id="FileSharePathEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="126" Width="250" Height="16" Property="WIXUI_FILESHAREDIR" Indirect="yes" />
    <Control Id="FileSharePathBrowse" Type="PushButton" X="280" Y="125" Width="56" Height="17" Text="Browse"/>
```

and the following Publish statements:

```
      <Publish Dialog="ConfigurationDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="ConfigurationDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="ConfigurationDlg" Control="FileSharePathBrowse" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_FILESHAREDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="ConfigurationDlg" Control="FileSharePathBrowse" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

When I use the browse button the FILESHAREDIR property ends up getting updated correctly. When I type into the text editor manually and hit Next, it doesn't and the FILESHAREDIR retains the incorrect default value at install time.

Am I missing a Publish statement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Property@Secure attribute to list the public property in the [SecureCustomProperties property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: For the WIXUI_FILESHAREDIR property? Tried that with no effect. Like <Property Id="WIXUI_FILESHAREDIR" Secure="yes">FILESHAREDIR</Property>

Comment: I'd have to log the install and see whats going on.  Somethings off the top of my head is why use a property?  Seems like it should be a Directory table id.

Comment: I used a property because it seems like convention (from the examples I've seen elsewhere) to wrap Directories/Properties for the UI by creating a property WIXUI_PropertyOrDirectoryId. Instlal log is fairly large...can I email it to you or is there another way to get it to you?

Comment: Also, note that it's not all sub-files/folders that are placed in the wrong directory...just some of them. I noticed that dynamically heat'ed directories and files were always ending up in the correct FILESHAREDIR...but not static ones... As a sanity check, I changed the Ids of my static sub-directories to dirXXXXXXXXX like all the heated ones have...and now the install is consistently going to the correct place...any idea what's going on?

Comment: Why would the naming of the directories matter? I checked and the subdirectories in question (NEWVERSIONDIR and REPORTSDIR) aren't being referenced anywhere else in the wxs files.

Comment: I'd really have to look at the installer as a whole and log it.  One thing to understand that if you have a parent child relationship like DIRA\DIRB\DIRC  if you change DIRA, DIRB and DIRC will follow along.  But if you change DIRB then change DIRA,  DIRB and DIRC won't follow.  The chain is broken.  Depending on what your directory table looks like you could have all kinds of differing behavior.

Comment: I have FILESHAREDIR with child dir POINTDIR, which has two child dirs NEWVERSIONDIR AND REPORTSDIR. Only FILESHAREDIR is configurable via the UI (via WIXUI_FILESHAREDIR). There are no other references to POINTDIR, NEWVERSIONDIR, or REPORTSDIR anywhere in the setup wxs files. If I change the IDs of those three directories so that they are like dirXXXXXXX (adding numbers to the end of the name doesn't work), then the files go to the correct place.

Comment: I'm happy to share whatever resources you think might help troubleshoot the issue